# strange error with Facebook Feed dialog

Tags: facebook

We followed the Facebook example code, shown here -- this works in our app -- if you click the anchor 'a' link, its onclick handler opens a new window and the facebook feed dialog appears:

```
      <a class="fbShareToWall" onClick='window.open("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123050457758177
       &link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/
       &picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg
       &name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation
       &description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.
       &redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response");'>Share on Facebook</a>
```

The above code works fine and displays the Facebook sample of the Feed dialog.

Here is our code - we get the error message:

**"An error occurred with oursite.com. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.**

NOTE: this is a beta site and we're running it on a staging server whose domain name is NOT the same as the domain name that "OUR_APP_ID" below is associated with:

```
            <a class="fbShareToWall" onClick='window.open("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id="OUR_APP_ID"
             &link=https://www.oursite.com&name=Please%20work
             &caption=Just%20work
             &description=Comeon%20work
             &redirect_uri=http://www.oursite.com");'>Share on Facebook</a>
```

(note: our code has the numerical FB app_id, not "OUR_APP_ID")

"OUR_APP_ID" is 'connected' to our production server's domain name and we're kinda wondering if that's the problem.

EDIT: "we're kinda wondering if that's the problem" because the code above is on our staging website www.foo.com --
and our code above uses an app_Id that we connected to our production domain name 'www.oursite.com'.

We wonder if Facebook -- upon receiving the above request to display the Feed dialog -- is saying to itself

**"okay this website www.foo.com is trying to display a Feed dialog -- but the app_id is for www.oursite.com --
so we're going to pop up a 191 error"**

We tested that theory.  We altered the sample FB feed dialog code at the top -- we changed some numbers in the sample code's app id.

And we get an error message now with the formerly working sample Feed dialog code but it is a completely different error message.

Any advice on this '191' redirect_uri error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the url format works fine with my app

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=135669679827333&link=https://anotherfeed.com&name=testing&caption=Just%20testing&description=the%20test&redirect_uri=http://anotherfeed.com
```

check to make sure your app id is correct and that your redirecting to the domain that is set up in your app settings.

Comment: I checked -- our AppId is associated to **oursite.com** and not **www.oursite.com** -- could that be the problem? Because in our code we don't use **oursite.com** -- we're using **www.oursite.com** figuring 'what's the difference.' Otherwise our code has the correct app_id that Facebook gave us for our www.oursite.com web site.

Comment: I modified the Feed dialog code to only use oursite.com and not www.oursite.com -- no change.  I looked at our app on our Facebook page and we have not specified any of the following --- do we need to? **App Namespace**;  **App Domain**; and none of the **Select how your app integrates with Facebook** things are selected either.  Could that be part of the problem?  Only the **App Display name** is filled in (with **oursite.com**, the name we use to create the app and get the app_id for it.)

Comment: you need to fully set up the app, and domain settings to use the feature.

Comment: Okay -  I just set up two previously un-set entries for the app:  **(1)** I set the *App Domain* field to **www.oursite.com** -- until now it was blank;  **(2)** I checked the *Website* integration option and entered **http://www.oursite.com** as the *Site URL* value.  I have to 'wait several minutes until my changes propagate to all FB servers' -- hopefully that will fix it.

Comment: OH MAN I am so good to go.  I got that dang Feed dialog whipped into shape buoy. Curious it took so much effort, the FB docs are so thorough.  /sarc